# In Android, why do you need the resource qualifier -mdpi if it is already the default?

Tags: android, android-resources

Say you have a `dimens.xml` file that goes in the `res/values` folder of your project. Then, you want to have some different dimensions based on screen density. So, for example, you can create `res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml` and `res/values-xxhdpi/dimens.xml` and have specific data for those configurations.

My question is, is there ever a reason to use `res/values-mdpi`? As I understand it, mdpi is the default density. Any values in the default values folder is considered mdpi so why is there ever a need for having `values-mdpi`?

Although I can think of a reason why you might have extra qualifiers such as `values-en-mdpi`, I don't see how `values-mdpi` is ever necessary when you can just put them in `values`.

Comment: You're right. That qualifier is redundant. There are many things that are redundant in Android. Most likely, there just wasn't a consensus one way, or an other.

Comment: There is never an absolute need to use -mdpi qualifier. But I think it's easier to understand.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk As I understand it resources in `values` will be picked up on all devices while resources in `values-mdpi` only on mdpi devices. So there clearly is a difference.

Comment: @Henry, I really doubt that's the case.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch

Comment: @StephanBranczyk You are right, I forgot about the special treatment of the density qualifier.